# 19.10: Thinkpad T495 showed 16GB RAM w/ Windows 10 but now shows only 13.6GB under Ubuntu

Tags: thinkpad

After paving over an install of Windows 10 on a [Thinkpad T495](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/thinkpad-t-series-laptops/thinkpad-t495-type-20nj-20nk) with Ubuntu 19.10, the total RAM memory shown in my system, which was 16 GB under Windows, is now showing only as 13.6 GB under Ubuntu.

Looking for any insight as to what is going on that would cause this discrepancy.

The command `cat /proc/meminfo|grep -i memtotal` shows `MemTotal: 14272168 kB`, 
which is 13.6 GB.

Comment: Please click [edit] then  add into your question 1) exactly which command with exactly which parameters you used to check on memory, and 2) the result of that command. Please don't use Add Comment as it throws away the formatting.

Comment: Show me `free -h`. And does the `AMD integrated graphics` card use shared memory?

Comment: Okay, ran it:

`$ free -h`
`              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available`
`Mem:           13Gi       1.8Gi        10Gi       134Mi       1.3Gi        11Gi`
`Swap:         975Mi          0B       975Mi`

Comment: When I boot into system bios setup it shows 16GB of RAM but under display it shows it using 2GB

So integrated graphics of the AMD looks to be sharing some of the system RAM

Also, I did take snapshots of various screens of the laptop booted up under Windows 10, I went back and reviewed those and low and behold I saw this:

Installed RAM: 16.0 GB (13.9 GB usable)

So Windows 10 was leaving 13.9 GB as usable whereas Ubuntu 19.10 is reporting 13.6 GB as usable. Almost a wash.

Will leave the item open for now in case anyone can share more light on the architecture going on here.